# angular-strap modal - pass variable into the modal scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-strap

How to pass variable in angular-strap modal?

Need to pass `item` params into the modal scope.

example.html :

```html
<div class="container" ng-controller="ExampleCtrl">
    <br>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-1">
            <div class="row jumbotron" ng-repeat="item in items">
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <h4>{{item.name}}</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" ng-click="showModal()">Custom Modal
                      <br />
                      <small>(using data-template)</small>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

example.controller.js :

```js
'use strict';

angular
    .module('MyApp')
    .controller('ExampleCtrl', ['$scope', '$modal',
        function ($scope, $modal) {
        var modal = $modal({
            scope: $scope,
            template: '../../views/example.tpl.html',
            show: false
        });
        $scope.showModal = function() {
            modal.$promise.then(modal.show);
        };
}]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not so clear what your problem is. `$modal` has by default the same scope as the page - after all a modal is just an element on that page.

So `scope: $scope` is completely unnessecary. As for the markup, "passing" a variable to the `$modal` is straight forward :

```js
$scope.item = { name : 'Holy guacamole'};
```

"Holy guacamole" will be shown in the modals  `<h4>{{ item.name }}</h4>`

Personally I prefer to create an object dedicated to a certain modal :

```js
$scope.myModalData = {
     item : {
        name : 'Holy guacamole'
     }
}
```

```html
<h4>{{ myModalData.item.name }}</h4>
```

---

***If*** you insist of using a custom scope, do this :

```js
var $modalScope = $scope.$new(true);
$modalScope.item = {
   name : 'Holy guacamole';
}
```

...

```
var modal = $modal({
   scope: $modalScope,
   template: '../../views/example.tpl.html',
   show: false
});
```

...

```
<h4>{{ item.name }}</h4>
```